# How to find highest green volume candle from last 5 candles in a strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am writing a basic strategy in pine script which triggers a buy position when ema is pointing upwards and any of the last 5 green volume candle is greater than avg 10 day volume.

Issue:

I am not able to match if the highest volume in the last 5 candle is from a green candle or a red candle. I tried looping over but that also did not work.

Code I came up with:

```
getHighestVol(fastLength) =>
    var float highestVolume = na
    var bool isGreenVol = na

    // Loop through last 5 candles
    for i = 1 to fastLength
        // Determine if current candle is green
        isGreenVol := close[i-1] >= close[i]
        // Update highest volume if current candle's volume is higher than previous highest
        if (volume[i-1] > highestVolume and isGreenVol)
            highestVolume := volume[i-1]
        
    highestVolume
```

But this gives me empty result. Image attached.
[image: Error image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store the volume data in a `var` array when it is a green candle. Then use `array.max()` to get the max value in your array.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

in_len = input.int(5, "Length")

f_add_to_arr(p_arr, p_val, p_max) =>
    len = array.size(p_arr)

    if ((len + 1) > p_max)
        array.shift(p_arr)
    
    array.push(p_arr, p_val)

var green_vol_arr = array.new_float()

is_green_candle = (close >= open)

if (is_green_candle)
    f_add_to_arr(green_vol_arr, volume, in_len)

max_green_vol = array.max(green_vol_arr)
plotchar(max_green_vol, "Max Green Volume", "")
```